# C Matching Algorithm (Using Recursion + Permutations)

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, matching

I have found a lot of research on the topic for my assignment that is close to what I want, but not exactly. It seems many assignments are forced to find the permutations of strings, which has as similar approach. I am a newbie to recursion and therefore have a hard time tracing the code. I have found this snippet in another post:

```
void swap(char* str, int i, int j)
{
    char temp = str[i];
    str[i] = str[j];
    str[j] = temp;
}

void permute(char *string, int start, int end)
{
    if(start == end)
   {
        printf("%s\n", string);
        return;
    }

    permute(string, start + 1, end);
    int i;
    for(i = start + 1; i < end; i++)
    {
        if(string[start] == string[i])
            continue;
        swap(string, start, i);
        permute(string, start + 1, end);
        swap(string, start, i);
    }
}
```

and from there I can see that the base case is when the length of the string is the same as the index of i. However, for my assignment we are to do something slightly different. We are asked to play "match maker" between possible couples. We are given an equal number of men and women, whom each have a "matchability" measure. Our goal is to maximize this matchability number. Therefore, if it was a 3 men * 3 women (always going to be perfect number of couples) I would have:

```
 {[M1, W1], {[M1, W1], {[M1, W2],
  [M2, W2],  [M2, W3],  [M2, W1],
  [M3, W3]}  [M3, W2]}  [M3, W3]}
  ....
  // Match #(n)! or in this case 6 (3*2*1)

;
```

and so on. I know that the resulting number of permutations will be (n)! where n is the number of couples. Therefore 10 men and 10 women would be (10)! solutions. With this all in mind, is this code I found similar to what I should be looking for, or does it need to be modified? I am believeing in must be modified because this is permuting a linear array where my case can be though of permuting two separate arrays.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to permute 2 seperate arrays - **you only need to permute one of them, and leave the other one constant while matching**. This is enough to guarantee you check all possible solutions to match men and women. Proving is simple, the `Men` are just the indices of the women, and all permutations of the women array are just finding all ways to order them - i.e. assigning all possibilities for indices for the women.

Let's have a look on a simple example of 3 men and 3 women:

```
data = [M1,M2,M3] [W1,W2,W3]
opt1: M1+W1, M2+W2, M3+W3
opt2: M1+W1, M2+W3, M3+W2
opt3: M1+W2, M2+W1, M3+W3
opt4: M1+W2, M2+W3, M3+W1
opt5: M1+W3, M2+W1, M3+W2
opt6: M1+W3, M2+W2, M3+W1
```

It is easy so see these are all the possibilities AND we only permuted the women array (`[W1,W2,W3]`) while the men array stayed as is.

---

**EDIT:**

Based on the code you already have, here is something that can be done:

```
int permute(int men[], int women[], int start, int end)
{
    if(start == end)
   {
        int i =0, sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < end; i++) sum += score(men[i],women[i]);
        return sum;
    }
    best = -INFINITY;
    best = max(permute(men, women, start + 1, end), best);
    int i;
    for(i = start + 1; i < end; i++)
    {
        if(women[start] == women[i])
            continue;
        swap(string, start, i);
        best = max(permute(men, women, start + 1, end), best);
        swap(women, start, i);
    }
    return best;
}
```

The above only permutes the `women`, and in the stop clause checks for the score (assuming int) and returns the "best" score found in the iterations (assuming best is the highest in here).

I also assumed you have some function `int score(int,int)` that finds the score for each match

**Note:** This is a c-style *pseudo code*, it was not tested and might have some syntax issues.

Comment: This looks good! However, I think my professor is looking for a recursive approach, but this looks like it is done linearly? Could you expand on that half of it? So would I just run a recursive function on the woman array for each man? So some pseudo code would look like: 1. Declare arrays. 2. For loop for size of men array. 3. For each man[i = 0; i++] in array, permute the women. However, I don't understand how I could flow that into saying I already pick M1 and W1, now M2 either gets W2 or W3, but I don't know how to account for both of those. You get waht I am saying?

Comment: @dsiebert424 Have a look on the edit, it can be done recursively where you check the score for each permutation in the base clause